# How to create a release branch in GIT?

Tags: git

I want to create a 'live-release' branch in GIT, so I can tell capistrano to pull the source from that branch.

Say I am in master, and now I am ready for a release, how can I push the code (FORCE) to the 'live-release' branch?

I want to force because I don't really care about merge conflicts, I just want to, whenever i am ready, to push to 'live-release'.

I want to avoid using master because it can be unstable.

Comment: What you really probably want to do is manage the live-release branch appropriately within your repository (check it out and merge master, or reset to master, and so on) and then when ready, simply run `git push [--force]` to push it (and all matching branches) to the remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming both branches are in the same repository, use:

```
git push --force . master:live-release
```

Or replace the `.` with the name (URL) of the live-release repository.

I'd recommend you don't use force. If you only ever push to `live-release` from `master` then there should never be a merge conflict. If you *do* see a conflict then something has gone horribly wrong that you probably want to fix before you clobber your `live-release` branch.

Comment: If you're doing this within a repository, all you have to do is `git branch -f live-release master`. No need to make git pretend to be pushing to a remote.

Comment: @Jefromi: Fair enough. I tend to use push/pull/rebase for local branches because any kind of "force" flag is generally A Bad Idea Unless You're Very Careful.